# Gzip xml string in the file using Java

Tags: java, gzip

Any help appreciated.
I have file in JSON format.
{
"identifier": 123;
"MessageID: "xyzzzzzz"
"Data": "xmlformattedstring"
}

I would like to just Gzip the ("xmlformattedstring") keeping the JSON body intact.
Is it possible to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035670/how-to-use-java-program-in-bean-pre-processor Solved

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could set the data with something like:

```
String data = "xmlformattedstring";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
gzos.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
gzos.close();

String base64CompressedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
```

and then use base64CompressedString in your JSON.  Basically all this does is compress your string and convert it to base64.  Base64 won't be as efficient as pure GZIP but it will be needed to send as an ASCII string like in JSON.

Comment: Actually my xml data is very long, I will not able to copy paste it here. I used this code but no change. my code is like  { "Data": "xmlformatted string" ,
  "SourceMessageIdentifier": "String",} i would like to gzip the data inside quote of "Data"

Comment: Are you constructing the JSON?  I showed how to compress a single String but we'd need to know a bit more about how that large string gets into the JSON.

Comment: I am copying XML file in string format from the file which is given by the  vendor. I need to put this file in Jmeter under "data" and then send JSON with gzip XML file. not the whole file. I am using JMeter to send the file.

Comment: That helped I am able to compress file, But unable to use same program in Jmeter Beanshell Pre-processor any idea how do i do that?

Comment: It working now for normal string, but fails  if full xml file is pasted there.