# How to use java program in bean pre-processor

Tags: jmeter

The below program reads the XML file and compress into gzip.

I have a couple of questions here.

1. Can I use the following program directly in JMeter BeanShell pre-processor?
2. I want to use the output variable as input to JSON request. Is it possible in Jmeter?
3. Screen shot and details will be appreciated.

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   ```
   String line = null; 
   String sb = "";
   File f=new File("D:\\RetailTransactionLog_9419_001_590.xml");
   FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);   

   while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   {
        sb= sb + line;
   }   
   br.close();


   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
   gzos.write(sb.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   gzos.close();

   String base64CompressedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
   System.out.println(base64CompressedString);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can put your piece of java code directly in a  JMeter BeanShell pre-processor and much more !

Insert you pre-processor component as child of your JSON request (as in my script example in attachment).

You don’t need to import java.io package  like BufferedReader, ByteArrayOutputStream, File, FileReader, IOException, Base64…

Remove also the main signature public static void main(String[] args) …

You only have to import "java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream" (A)

I’ve also replace your System.out.println(base64CompressedString) by log.info(base64CompressedString) just to visualize in the jmeter console your output (B)…

[image]

And finally add at the end, the code (C) to reference your result in the variable  of your choice ("a" in my example).

You just have to call your variable after with ${a} in your json request like in my JMX script :

[image]

Unzip attachments http://uplea.com/dl/9F734367B43FB93 :

"ReadAndCompressMyFile.jmx" under /bin and put "test.xml"  under C: or change the path in your code.

I’ve used a dummy sampler instead of your json request.

After running my script, you can see in View Result Tree (Request tab) and in the console, the value of "a" (corresponding to base64CompressedString).

[image]

PS : To run my script with the "dummy sampler", you need to add jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.1.jar under /lib/ext of your jmeter directory.

Hope to help you...

Comment: That worked fine, thank you very much. I modified the program to take the value from string rather than file but it fails becasue my string contents xml data. is there any way to handle xml string directly in program?

Answer (score 0):

GZIP compression is rather "heavy" operation, if you will have lots of virtual users - it may become a bottleneck so consider using other approaches:

1. There is [__base64Encode()](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function available via JMeter plugins
2. If for any reason it is not enough - go for [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](http://Beanshell%20vs%20JSR223%20vs%20Java%20JMeter%20Scripting:%20The%20Performance-Off%20You've%20Been%20Waiting%20For!), Groovy is mostly compatible with Java so your code should work fine (just remove `main` method)

Comment: I will try this approach, Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: HI Dmitri Thanks for alternate solution, could you please tell me sytnax for base64Encode() or an example. I have sample string satored in variable Data. Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be something like `${__base64Encode(${your_variable_here},)}`. Actually JMeter functions syntax is a little bit scary so I use Functions Helper Dialog all the time (Options -> Functions Helper Dialog from JMeter main menu). See [Using JMeter Functions](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733749-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-I) article for more information

Comment: I have coded like this  data = "abcdefgh";
${__base64Encode(data,)}
vars.put("a", data);  There is no change in ouput. I have put dummy sample to verify output, the output string is same as input string. Am I doing anything wrong in this script. Please help